# Guava Cache - quickly return initial value and do async refresh

Tags: guava

I am trying to implement "cache entry enrichment" behavior:

1. When the key is new/outdated for the cache, return the quickly precalculated value and trigger async recalculation for the key
2. Once async recalculation is done, return the updated value

The following code implements that, but is obviously dramatically bad. Is there a way to achieve that by pure cache config?

### Code+Test:

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GuavaCacheTest {

    final LoadingCache<Long, String> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .build(
                    new CacheLoader<Long, String>() {

                        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

                        public String load(Long key) {
                            System.out.println("load() " + key);
                            return "INITIAL";
                        }

                        public ListenableFuture<String> reload(final Long key, String prevString) {
                            // asynchronous!
                            ListenableFutureTask<String> task = ListenableFutureTask.create(() -> {
                                System.out.println("reload() started for ... " + key);

                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                System.out.println("reload() ended for ... " + key);

                                return "Calculated value for " + key;

                            });
                            executor.execute(task);
                            return task;
                        }

                    });


    public String myget(Long key) {
        String v = myCache.getUnchecked(key);

        if (v == "INITIAL") {
            myCache.refresh(key);
            myCache.getUnchecked(key);

            v = "Initial value for " + key;
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void testRepeatedCalls() {


        System.out.println("Call result: " + myget(55L));
        System.out.println("Call result: " + myget(55L));
        System.out.println("Call result: " + myget(55L));
        System.out.println("Call result: " + myget(55L));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("---------------");

        System.out.println("Call result: " + myget(55L));
        System.out.println("Call result: " + myget(55L));
        System.out.println("Call result: " + myget(55L));
        System.out.println("Call result: " + myget(55L));

    }

}
```

### Output:

```
load() 55
reload() started for ... 55
Call result: Initial value for 55
Call result: Initial value for 55
Call result: Initial value for 55
Call result: Initial value for 55
reload() ended for ... 55
---------------
Call result: Calculated value for 55
Call result: Calculated value for 55
Call result: Calculated value for 55
Call result: Calculated value for 55
```

Comment: Consider caching futures (such as Caffeine's `AsyncLoadingCache`). Then if the returned future is incomplete (loading) you return the precomputed result (e.g. using `CompletableFuture.getNow(precomputed)`).

Comment: @BenManes thanks, that worked well. Of course assuming replacing the cache engine is possible ;)